# Should all NFT minting contracts be ERC-721 complient?

Tags: nft, erc-721

If there is a contract that emits `Trasfer` `events` with a unique id in each mint request (showing the core property of an `NFT` contract), but not provide all the other interfaces required by `ERC-721`, is the unique ID emitted still considered an `NFT`? If not, am I right to belive

> a unique id generated by an `ERC-721` complaint contract

be the technical definition of an NFT.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily, there is [EIP-1155](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1155).

In theory a contract could generate events that matches EIP-721 (or EIP-1155) and do something entirely different. The thing is for an "NFT" to be considered and "NFT" by the public it has to be accepted by known markets, and wallets. For example CryptoPunks (`0xb47e3cd837ddf8e4c57f05d70ab865de6e193bbb`) doesn't follow a standard and it is considered an NFT.

Comment: Does this mean there is no clear agreement to the definition of how a non-fungible object should be represented in the ethereum chain?

Comment: @EHM I won't say so. CryptoPunks and CryptoKitties are treated differently because of their status as the first NFTs. Nowadays if you want to write an NFT the EIP-721 and EIP-1155 are the accepted solutions by markets and wallets. You could write a non-standard NFT, but you'll have a hard time convincing others to use it, it is not impossible but it will be difficult.